# How can I use same step from step definition for 2 feature file

Tags: java, cucumber, gherkin

```
eg 
Home.feature
Given User is in the website Landing page


Search.feature
Given User is in the website Landing page
```

`Given User is in the website Landing page` is the HomeSteps.java step file

here is the step file:

```
@Given("User is in the Home page")
    public void user_is_in_the_home_page() {
        driver = DriverFactory.getDriver();
        homePage = new HomePage(driver);
    }
```

an error : `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Input must be set` is thrown

how to fix this? or is there a way to create a common file for step definition that connects 2 or more feature?

Comment: Please provide a full stack trace of the exception. The same step can be reused by multiple features. The exception you see most likely comes from the DriverFactory.getDriver() line.